# least date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Sample table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O8Gh.gif]

Hi, can someone pl. help how do I get the least date and corresponding name from the table above? I should get only 3 rows, with first one as Ram and second one as def and third one as def.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subquery` or *ranking* function :

```
select * 
from table t
where StartTime = (select min(StartTime) from table where Id = t.Id);
```

You can also use `row_number` ranking function

```
select * 
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by Id order by StartTime) Seq
      from table t
     ) t
where Seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [a special case of a `top N per category` style query](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/), which can be implemented efficiently in Oracle.

#### [Using Oracle's `FIRST` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641)

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  MIN(name)      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY starttime) name,
  MIN(starttime) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY starttime) starttime
FROM t
GROUP BY id
```

Other solutions include:

#### Window functions

```
SELECT id, name, starttime
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, name, starttime, 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY starttime) rn
  FROM t
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

#### Subqueries

[As suggested by Yogesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350049/521799), but they're way slower than the above solutions.